# Multiple Inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set a Error Message under my Input Fields, if the value isn't valid. The message will always be the same. But the message is shown on every Input field, if the value isn't valid. That's logic if you see the code. But how can I make it work?

And yes, I have to use the error state in the Parent component because I have lifted the state up. Because of style dependencies of the error prop. I'm using styled-components for that.

Parent component:

```
const List = (props) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  function handleChange(event) {
    const currentValue = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    if (currentValue > 10) {
      setError('Error');
    } else setError(null);
  }
  return (
      {items.map(item => (
        <MyInput
          value={item.value}
          key={item.input}
          error={error}
          handleChange={e => handleChange(e)}
        />

      ))}
  );
};

export default List;
```

The child Component:

```
const MyInput = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
            <input
              defaultValue={props.value}
              type="text"
              placeholder={props.value}
              onChange={e => props.handleChange(e)}
            />
      {props.error ? {props.error} : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default MyInput;
```

Is it possible to use the state in the parent component?
I hope you can help me :)

Comment: items is an array of multiple values and error is a string of a single value. You are sharing one error with an array of items.

Comment: For that, either you have to handle the state in the inner component, or have a separate error state for each input. For now you are sharing single error state with all your input fields

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb  You both are right. That was stupid. I thought, that if i want to change styles in styled-components conditional on state, I have to lift it up. But I switch the handleChange and the error state to the child. and give the input the state as a prop. And so I can use the conditional styles with the error prop in styled.components :) Thank you very much!